# An elementary proof of convergence of $\left[\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\text{d}x\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given that $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function, show that the sequence $\left[\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\text{d}x\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent.

*Proof:* Write $a_n = \left[\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\text{d}x\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Let $M = \sup\{|f(x)|:0 \leq x \leq 1\}.$ Then $a_n\leq M$ for every $n$, so $\lim\sup a_n \leq M.$ Since $[0,1]$ is compact, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an interval $I_{\epsilon}\subseteq[0,1]$ of positive length such that $M-\epsilon\leq|f(x)|\leq M$ for every $x \in I_{\epsilon}.$ Then
$$a_n\geq\left[\int_{I_{\epsilon}}|f(x)|^n\text{d}x\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq[(M-\epsilon)^n\cdot\text{length}(I_{\epsilon})]^{\frac{1}{n}}=(M-\epsilon)\cdot[\text{length}(I_{\epsilon})]^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$
Hence $\lim\inf a_n\geq M-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$; therefore $\lim\inf a_n\geq M$ and hence $\lim a_n =M.\square$

My question is - are there any other, simpler ways to prove it?

Comment: I think that is the standard proof. Perhaps you can find another one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/88300.

Comment: Why $\;\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\ge M-\epsilon\;$? We only know that $\;\big[\text{length}(I_\epsilon)\big]^{\frac{1}{n}}<1\;.\;$

Comment: @Angelo $(\text{length}(I_{\epsilon}))^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ as you take the limit.

Comment: @tmaj, you are right, you have also calculated the limit inferior of the right-hand side.

Comment: I don't think there's a whole lot of getting around the fact that deriving a lower bound is more difficult.